# How to find list of tables having no records in SQL server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

How to display a list of tables having no record in them and they are existing in the sql server database.Required is only to show tables with no record in them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows = 0
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

The query goes to the `sys.tables` and other catalog views to find the tables, their indexes and partitions, to find those tables that have a row count of 0.

Comment: Why query needs t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'  ?

Comment: Maybe it's a copy paste from here https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Listing%20all%20tables%20in%20a%20database%20and%20their%20row%20counts%20and%20sizes.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Alteration to add Schema names:

```
SELECT 
    sch.name,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
inner Join sys.schemas sch
    on t.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows = 0
GROUP BY 
    sch.name,t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    sch.name,t.Name
```

Comment: I have a table for which `select * from schema.table` returns zero rows. But when I ran orgtrigger's schema version, it says that table has one row. Why is that? (I also tried jazb's query, but that returned 0 rows, presumably because it also is determining that the table in question has one row.)

Answer (score 0):

I found some of the previous answers still returned tables *with* data for me.

However, the following seems to correctly on report those with no rows (using `SQL Server 2019`):

```
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name AS [table]
FROM sys.tables tab
INNER JOIN sys.partitions part ON tab.object_id = part.object_id
WHERE part.index_id IN (
        1
        ,0
        ) -- 0 - table without PK, 1 table with PK
GROUP BY schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name
HAVING sum(part.rows) = 0
ORDER BY [table]
```