# SQL query - return table name with 0 row

Tags: sql, null, rows

How do you query in SQL if I want to return the table name if that table is null?

for example?

```
table1 = 3 rows
table2 = 1 row
table3 = 0 row
```

the query will return the table name "table3" since it has 0 rows.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606878/how-to-find-list-of-tables-having-no-records-in-sql-server

Comment: it is working but what if i have a range of tables?

Comment: Yope The example provided by @MatthewSiddle seems to do the trick. I have used variants of that same query for similar purposes. If this is not meeting your needs, you'll need to be a bit more specific as to what need is not being met.

Answer (score 0):

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rowcount > 0) {

```
      printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
```

} else {

```
      echo 'Persons'; // table name

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS), TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

or if you are using ms sql, there is a report that can give you that info

right click, reports, standard reports and go for disk usage by top tables, there will be number of records along with other info.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_ROWS = 0;` will return the tables with 0 rows.

The above statement will not be particularly useful as it returns table names in all the databases including system.

So filtering on `TABLE_SCHEMA` will get us tables with 0 rows only on the interested databases.

**Final:**
`SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_ROWS = 0 and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databaseName';`