# Select first N rows of all non-empty SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm performing a database migration to a new ERP system, and the current Microsoft SQL database has well over 3000 tables, 95% of which have no data causing a lot of grief/noise in figuring out the schema.

Is there a way I can print the header and first three rows of data for every table that is non-empty from the database?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could easily do that with a CURSOR and dynamic SQL.

Comment: Using a cursor you could. Just use `not exists` with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606929/6167855) to exclude the tables with no data

Comment: If you use the undocumented sp_MSforeachtable below... [be sure to read this first](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server has the unsupported `sp_MSforeachtable`.  So, you can do:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='select top (3) * from ? where exists (select 1 from ?)';
```

Otherwise, you would be using a cursor or other looping mechanism to achieve basically the same thing.

EDIT:

Jeroen makes a very good suggestion:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='if exists (select 1 from ?) select top (3) ''?'' as table_name, t.* from ? t';
```

This also adds the table name for extra spice.

Comment: This will give a bunch of empty result sets. Consider `if exists (...) select ...`. (And it will still be missing table names, so the `print` from the other answer is probably also a good idea.)

Comment: This is perfect.... for what it's worth to others that may look my question up, I ran this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and selected Query -> Results to -> Results to File such that I now have a dump I can easily reference and print to leaf through.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Is there a way to take this a step further and also not show columns with no data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_MSforeachtable` function

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'PRINT ''?''; SELECT TOP 3 * FROM ?'
```