# How to list all tables that have data in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have around 2000 tables that most of them are not in use and do not have any data in them.
I know how to list all tables as below

```
SELECT owner, table_name FROM ALL_TABLES
```

But I do not know how to list the one that has at least one row of data in it.
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: If you have collected statistics on your schema, you could then just do `select table_name from dba_tables where num_rows > 0;`

Comment: You will find the answer here. **link** : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606878/how-to-find-list-of-tables-having-no-records-in-sql-server

Comment: @ShuchitaRahamn - that answer is tagged `[sql-server]` whereas this question is tagged `[oracle]`. They are different RDBMS products, and while SQL statements are often transferrable across both platforms this is unlikely to be true for data dictionary queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this:

- Brute-force and count the rows in every table
- Check the table stats
- Check if there is any storage allocated

**Brute force**

This loops through the tables, counts the rows, and spits out those that are empty:

```
declare
  c integer;
begin
  for t in (
    select table_name from user_tables
    where  external = 'NO'
    and    temporary = 'N'
  ) loop
    execute immediate 
      'select count(*) from ' || t.table_name
    into c;
    if c = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line ( t.table_name );
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is the only way to be sure there are no rows in the table *now*. The main drawback to this is it could take a looooong time if you a many tables with millions+ rows.

I've excluded:

- Temporary tables. You can only see data inserted in your session. If they're in use in another session you can't see this
- External tables. These point to files on the database server's file system. The files could be temporarily missing/blank/etc.

There may be other table types with issues like these - make sure you double check any that are reported as empty.

**Check the stats**

If all the table stats are up-to-date, you can check the `num_rows`:

```
select table_name
from   user_tables ut
where  external = 'NO'
and    temporary = 'N'
and    num_rows = 0;
```

The caveat with this is this figures may be out-of-date. You can force a regather now by running:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats ( user );
```

Though this is likely to take a while and - if gathering has been disabled/deferred - might result in unwanted plan changes. Avoid doing this on your production database!

**Check storage allocation**

You can look for tables with no segments allocated with:

```
select table_name 
from   user_tables ut
where  external = 'NO'
and    temporary = 'N'
and    segment_created = 'NO';
```

As there's no space allocated to these, there's definitely no rows in them! But a table could have space allocated but no rows in it. So it may omit some of the empty tables - this is particularly likely for tables that did have rows in the past, but are empty now.

**Final thoughts**

It's worth remembering that a table with no rows *now* could still be in use. Staging tables used for daily/weekly/monthly loads may be purged at the end of the process; removing these will still break your apps!

There could also be code which refers to empty tables which work as-is, but would error if you drop the table.

A better approach would be to enable auditing, then run this for "a while". Any tables will no audited access in the time period are *probably* safe to remove.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the complete explanation and time you have spend to answer my question.